# Javascript function Arguments object becomes the current webpack module magically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I'm building a React application w/ Redux and in the `mapDispatchToProps` function - I'm using the pattern below.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  debugger
  Object.keys(actions).forEach(key => {
    var functionObj = actions[key];
    actions[key] = () => {
      debugger
      var zz = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      dispatch(functionObj.apply(null,zz));
    }
  });

  return actions;
}
```

Whats driving me bananas is that the arguments object is what I expect it to be (Array like object with the parameters bla bla) except when I "use" it in any way. By "use" I mean:

Assign it to something (like `var zz` above) OR pass it to a function.  When I "use" the arguments object - it magically becomes the current Webpack module that I am currently in.

Does anyone know anything about this?  Am I crazy??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that arrow functions [do not provide an `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments). So you are referencing the [module wrapper function](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/), which is the nearest non-arrow function.

You can fix this by using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead. Good riddence! Rest parameters are a true array and do not need to be converted with any [Array#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) nonsense.

Below is an example, where I also used the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to avoid the need to use [Function#apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), since you don't seem to need any special `this` value.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  debugger
  Object.keys(actions).forEach(key => {
    var functionObj = actions[key];
    actions[key] = (...zz) => {
      debugger
      dispatch(functionObj(...zz));
    }
  });

  return actions;
}
```

Comment: Omg.  Duh. You deserve a giant kiss on the mouth.  You don't have a choice, get over here.

Comment:   I know, it's non-intuitive at first. Rest parameters will become second nature eventually and we will forget about `arguments` and all of its shenanigans.

Comment: I salute you sir! Confirmed works.  Will accept answer in 2 minutes